# List Displays Data in Sencha Architect Design Mode but not in Preview or Build

Tags: listview, sencha-architect, tabpanel, sencha-touch-2.2

I have a list view in a container, in turn in a form panel, in turn in a tab panel with correctly configured rest proxy and json reader. When viewed in Sench Architect 2 design mode, I can see the data items and scroll around. When I run however, the list portion of the screen is blank: just the search field docked at the top shows.

I've been fiddling at this for hours with no success, help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias: 'widget.MainTab',

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Customer',
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'formpanel',
                    scrollable: 'vertical',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: {
                                type: 'fit'
                            },
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'searchfield',
                                    placeHolder: 'Type customer name'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'list',
                                    docked: 'bottom',
                                    height: 431,
                                    ui: 'round',
                                    itemTpl: [
                                        '<div>{Name}</div>'
                                    ],
                                    store: 'CustomersStore',
                                    itemHeight: 25,
                                    striped: true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'SKU'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Invoice'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Payment'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Reason found: the console revealed there was an "Origin .... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" so I suppose I need to use JsonP.

What remains baffling to me is I am running this Sencha app from `http://localhost/...` whilst my REST service points to `http://localhost:8080/...`

How come then this is seen as a different origin?

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that you have taken 2 controls in the container with fit layout. you have 2 options here.
Option 1: make searchfield docked on top

```
// your code {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: {
             type: 'fit'
        },
        items: [
            {
                  xtype: 'searchfield',
                  placeHolder: 'Type customer name',
                  docked: 'top'//Set docked top,
            },
            {
                 xtype: 'list',
                 docked: 'bottom',
                 height: 431,
                 ui: 'round',
                 itemTpl: [
                      '<div>{Name}</div>'
                 ],
                 store: 'CustomerStore',
                 itemHeight: 25,
                 striped: true
             }
     ]}
```

Option 2: set Layout of container vbox and define height of list using flex

```
{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'vbox'//set layout style to vbox 
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'searchfield',
                                placeHolder: 'Type customer name'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'list',
                                docked: 'bottom',
                                height: 431,
                                ui: 'round',
                                itemTpl: [
                                    '<div>{raceDate}</div>'
                                ],
                                store: 'MyNotes',
                                itemHeight: 25,
                                striped: true,
                                flex: 1//define height of list view
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```